# POST sails server api and react client 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: reactjs, api, post, sails.js, axios

i use sails server api and i post from axios react but error  500 (Internal Server Error).
here code client

```js
export default function callApi2(endpoint, method = 'GET', body) {
  
  let headers = { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
  console.log(body);
  
  return axios({
    method: method,
    url: `${Config.API_URL2}/${endpoint}`,
    data: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },

  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

here code server

```js
    postCommunication: async (req, res)=>{
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');

      let newCommunication = req.body;
      console.log(newCommunication);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(newCommunication));


      let resulfCommunication = await Communication.create(JSON.stringify(newCommunication)).fetch();
      return  res.json(resulfCommunication);
    },
```

Comment: Please put the code in question itself instead of images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP Status of 500 indicates something crashed on the server side.  This happened because you passed a wrong content type on your Axios code which should be `"application/json"`

```
export default function callApi2(endpoint, method = 'GET', body) {

  let headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
  console.log(body);

  return axios({
    method: method,
    url: `${Config.API_URL2}/${endpoint}`,
    data: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Since you mentioned that CORS headers are not also required, you can remove the code below as well:

```
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

Welcome to StackOverflow, if you find this answer helpful, you can mark it as an answer so it can help people with the same problem you experienced.

Comment: if i set it 'application/json' then method get all data error:  Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: export const actFecthCommunicationReq = ()=>{
    return (dispatch)=>{
    
        return callApi2('communication', 'GET', null).then(res =>{
            dispatch(actFecthCommunication(res.data));
        });
    }
}

Comment: no, this is code server sails communication:     getAllCommunication: async (req, res)=>{
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');


      let communications = await Communication.find();
      return  res.json(communications);

    },